# Redirect a URL with Post data

Tags: php, post

I want to redirect a user from page1 to page2 with some POST data .Page1 and page2 are on **two different domains** and i have control over **both** of them

Page 1

```
<?php
$chars="stackoverflowrules"
?>
```

I want to submit the chars as a post data and the redirect to page 2.

Then one page 2 i want to use the POST data like

```
<?php
$token = $_POST['chars'];
echo $token;
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did it using a form and JS

On page 1

```
<?php
$chars="stackoverflowrules";
?>
<html>
<form name='redirect' action='page2.php' method='POST'>
<input type='hidden' name='chars' value='<?php echo $chars; ?>'>
<input type='submit' value='Proceed'>
</form>
<script type='text/javascript'>
document.redirect.submit();
</script>
</html>
```

On page 2

```
<?php
$token = $_POST['chars'];
echo $token;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. On page 1, use [`curl`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to post the data to page 2.
2. There, store the POST'ed data somewhere (database?).
3. Redirect from page 1 to page 2
4. Retrieved the data back.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [`curl()`](http://php.net/curl) for this.

On page1.php, do the following:

```
$data = $_POST; 

// Create a curl handle to domain 2
$ch = curl_init('http://www.domain2.com/page2.php'); 

//configure a POST request with some options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

//put data to send
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);  

//this option avoid retrieving HTTP response headers in answer
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

//we want to get result as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//execute request
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// now redirect to domain 2
header("Location: http://domain2.com/page2.php");
```

On page 2, you may retrieve the POST data:

```
<?php

$token = $_POST['secure_token'];
echo $token;

?>
```

Comment: This won't work as expected, because there are 2 requests to page 2 now. One is the POST from curl. Second is the GET from `header()`. You're trying to get $_POST from the latter, which will not work.